# What is the substitue for the attr_protected in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

```
class Oregano < ApplicationRecord
  attr_protected :person_id
end
```

This throws me back with an error

```
/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:21:in `method_missing': undefined method `attr_protected' for #<Class:0x000055b38448bd58> (NoMethodError).
```

What should be the substitue in the rails 5 upgrade for this?

Comment: Check https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 1):

No mass assignment allowed for Rails 5

Instead of having attr_protected `:person_id` in your model, use strong parameters. You'll do this in your OreganosController:

```
def oregano_params
  params.require(:oregano).permit(:person_id)
end
```